# How to simulate same Google reCaptcha in other devide?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests, recaptcha

I have a selenium robot which do some scrapping.
My cliente don't want to use api's like 2captcha.
And make the user which request the robot receive the captcha and solve it manually.
Are there any project or solution to do that?
Get the code of the recaptcha of the selenium robot and render the same recaptcha in other html page, after it get the solution code and send back.
It's like a small implementation of 2captcha system.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the right place to ask for software library recommendations, so this question currently isn't suitable for this site. Take a look at the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for guidance about Stack Overflow.